# How to download Azure universal packages using Azure DevOps Python API

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to find documentation on how to use [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) in order to download universal packages from Azure private feeds.

Has anyone did it before using a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid downloading Azure universal packages using Azure DevOps Python API is not support yet. For the NPM, Maven, Nuget and Pyton Artifacts package types there is an API which allows directly downloading of a packages, but not for Azure universal packages.

The [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/download-universal-package-trough-api/495533) regarding this request has been submit to Microsoft Development team. You can vote it up, or create one for yourself.

Currently, you will have to download it using Azure CLI.

`az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/Fabrikam --feed FabrikamFiber --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --path .`

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops#download-a-universal-package) for more information.